# Erro no SelectedValue de um dropdownlist no ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho um formulário em Asp.Net para cadastro de veículos, onde existem `DropDownList` que são preenchidos com dados do banco. Porém ao clicar no Gravar ele retorna o erro

> System.Exception: 'NAO FOI POSSIVEL GRAVAR
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'dpModelo' tem um SelectedValue
>   que é inválido porque ele não existe na lista de itens.

Segue o codigo:

```
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CarregarDono();
            CarregarModelo();
        }

        BLL_Cliente bllcliente = new BLL_Cliente();
        BLL_Modelo bllmodelo = new BLL_Modelo();
        BLL_Veiculo bllveiculo = new BLL_Veiculo();
        DTO_Veiculo veiculo = new DTO_Veiculo();

        private void Limpar()
        {
            txtPlaca.Text = "";
            txtAno.Text = "";
            dpCor.Text = "";
            dpModelo.Text = "";
            dpDono.Text = "";

        }

        private void CarregarDono()
        {
            dpDono.DataSource = bllcliente.ListarClientes();
            dpDono.DataValueField = "id";
            dpDono.DataTextField = "nome";
            dpDono.DataBind();
        }

        private void CarregarModelo()
        {
            dpModelo.DataSource = bllmodelo.ListarTodosModelos();
            dpModelo.DataValueField = "id";
            dpModelo.DataTextField = "nome";
            dpModelo.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                veiculo.Placa = txtPlaca.Text;
                veiculo.Ano = txtAno.Text;
                veiculo.Cor = dpCor.SelectedValue;
                veiculo.Id_dono = int.Parse(dpDono.SelectedValue);
                veiculo.Id_modelo = int.Parse(dpModelo.SelectedValue);
                bllveiculo.InserirVeiculo(veiculo);

               string message = "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso";
                Response.Write("<script>alert('" + message + "');</script>");
                Limpar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                { throw new Exception("NAO FOI POSSIVEL GRAVAR" + ex); }
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: Onde acontece o erro no `bllInserir.InserirVeiculo()`? você debugou o código e verificou que está de fato recebendo um valor cálido para o `Id_Modelo` (que não é null e existe no banco de dados)?

Comment: Na vdd ele não dá erro na bll ele dá erro no "veiculo.Id_modelo = int.Parse(dpModelo.SelectedValue);" mas acabei de verificar no debug e ele recebe um valor valido sim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois que algum tempo testando e pensando achei onde estava o erro no meu Código.
No método Limpar() ele chama

> dpCor.Text = "";
>
> dpModelo.Text = "";
>
> dpDono.Text = "";

Isso fazia com que as variáveis ficassem vazias e então não recebiam um valor valido.Depois de apagar essas 3 linhas e colocar o ***PostBack*** como o amigo mencionou deu tudo certo.
**Muito Obrigado pela Atenção de todos.**

Answer (score 2):

Acontece que ao dar um *PostBack* na aplicação ele passa novamente pelo `Page_Load` e recarrega o `DropDownList`, para evitar isso use o `if(!IsPostBack){}`, ele irá verificar se é a primeira vez que você entra na página, ou seja, se você já entrou na tela e realiza um *PostBack*(clicar em um botão) ele não irá entrar no `if`.

seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
        CarregarDono();
        CarregarModelo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Amigo acho que esse era um dos fatores mas o problema persiste.